# What is this Windows Vista/7 window doing on the wall in episode 3 of Re-Kan?

Tags: re-kan

Around 17 seconds into episode 3 of *Re-Kan!*, there is this weird window (as in GUI element) from Windows Vista or Windows 7 on the wall of the classroom.

[image]

Another screenshot at around 07:22 in episode 1, showing the window in the lower right corner.

[image]

Looking through all 3 episodes which are aired so far, the charts and the weird window are consistently animated. While the animation is consistent, the choice of article to place on the wall is still weird. The window element looks completely out of place.

Is this an animation mistake?

Comment: It's definitely Windows 7, because of the Windows Aero transparency in the top bar.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin: The context is before class, when everyone is arriving at school. And if this were a presentation, it is rather weird why the whole wall is not filled up. Note that this is set in a normal school, not futuristic or rich kids school.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin: I'm going to post another screen shot from episode 1. It is really there. While the charts being stuck on the wall may make sense, the window GUI doesn't. About the top right corner, it's for ringing a bell, though I don't know when it would actually be used.

Comment: These look like printed screenshots for students' information. The window one with red rectangle around some buttons probably serves as an instruction (very important buttons are within the red rectangle).

Answer (score 20):

It's a screenshot from LMTOOLS by Flexera Software. As it's a tool for working with a software licencing management server, I think you're right and it's out place on the wall of an average Japanese highschool.  It hard to see such a specialized tool being the subject of instruction, and the screenshot alone stuck to a wall wouldn't serve any purpose.

I'm guessing the screenshot was grabbed from the Internet somewhere. Like this one I found on as part of a [FAQ entry on using the tool](https://www.aldec.com/en/support/resources/documentation/faq/1280):

[image: LMTOOLS by Flexera Software screenshot]

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Comment: @Pranab It wasn't too hard to figure out that the fuzzy text in the in title bar said something like "??TOOLS by Xxxxxx Software". Then I just tried a few guesses on what the ?? part was.

Comment: Maybe it's an inside joke from one of the animators, the kind of joke that only a few selected crew members will get.